# Is it possible to mock an Attribute Directive in Angular?

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have the following directive that is applied to input tags. When running a jasmine spec on the host component I want it to ignore (mock) this directive since it has a dependency on jquery that I am not interested in testing.

I have tried to create a `MockDirective` class but have not been successful. Anyone know how achieve this?

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[skinColorPicker]'
})
export class ColorPickerDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input('skinColorPicker') initialColor;

    @Output() colorSelected: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

    ngOnInit() {

       // legacy jQuery blah blah
    }
}
```

inside the host:

```
<input skinColorPicker="'#555'" (colorSelected)="onPageBackgroundColorSelected($event)" 
 />
```

the spec:

```
describe('PrintSidebarComponent', () => {
  let component: PrintSidebarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PrintSidebarComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
          PrintSidebarComponent,
          MockDirective({ selector: '[skinColorPicker]' }) // does not work
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PrintSidebarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

export function MockDirective(options: Component): Component {
    let metadata: Directive = {
        selector: options.selector,
        inputs: options.inputs,
        outputs: options.outputs
    };
    return Directive(metadata)(class _ { });
}
```

> Can't bind to 'skinColorPicker' since it isn't a known property of
>   'input'.

I saw [this overrideDirective method](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/testing/components/overriding.html) but have not been able to find a decent example of it.

**One Solution**
Turned out to be a missing mock declaration for the `@Input('skinColorPicker')` property:

```
MockDirective({selector: '[skinColorPicker]', inputs: ['skinColorPicker']})
```

I still think seeing an example with the built in `Testbed.overrideDirective` function would be better.

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/sKRmPFAyVHoD3FAm5cgZ?p=preview)

Comment: Why should you mock it? Is it not working without mocking? Angular will not complain on attribute directive if you don't declare it in `declarations` array. Anyway there is `NO_ERROR_SCHEMA` for this purpose

Comment: @yurzui i am mocking it mainly because it is not the system under test, but also because it has a legacy dependency on jQuery that i am not interested into bringing into my test suite.

Comment: the error is still evident without the declaration, `schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]` is needed to prevent it, but that feels like sweeping it under the carpet (try ... catch.. continue.. crap)

Comment: Can you reproduce it here? https://plnkr.co/edit/sKRmPFAyVHoD3FAm5cgZ?p=preview

Comment: short answer: no. but it helped me solve it. i had 2 pickers in the html one with a default value, so had to add the input to the mock: `MockDirective({selector: '[skinColorPicker]', inputs: ['skinColorPicker']})`. thank you.

Comment: `skinColorPicker="#555"` is key point in your question. In this case angular will complain if you don't declare @Input for your directive

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `MockDirective` does work, but it was misconfigured.

```
export function MockDirective(options: Component): Directive {
    const metadata: Directive = {
        selector: options.selector,
        inputs: options.inputs,
        outputs: options.outputs
    };
    return Directive(metadata)(class _ { });
}
```

Turned out to be a missing mock declaration for the `@Input('skinColorPicker')` property:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
      PrintSidebarComponent,
      MockDirective({ 
        selector: '[skinColorPicker]', 
        inputs: ['skinColorPicker'] }) // does work
  ]
})
```

Comment: Don't think this compiles in modern TypeScript. Is there any less voodoo way of creating a mock directive?

Comment: @SebastianPatten see my answer below

Comment: I wonder, with this approach, is it possible to test the input values of the directive?

Answer (score 10):

My solution is identical to @jenson-button-event's solution, with some minor changes so it compiles in TypeScript.

```
export function MockDirective(options: Component): Directive {
  const metadata: Directive = {
    selector: options.selector,
    inputs: options.inputs,
    outputs: options.outputs
  };
  return <any>Directive(metadata)(class _ {}); // <----- add <any>
}

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
      PrintSidebarComponent,
      MockDirective({ 
        selector: '[skinColorPicker]', 
        inputs: []  // <--- empty, unless the directive has inputs
      })
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 6):

This solution is exactly the same as @jenson-button-event's and @maia's solution, except for improved Typescript correctness. Without the improvements it did not work for me.

```js
export function MockDirective(options: Component): Type<Directive> {
  const metadata: Directive = {
    selector: options.selector,
    inputs: options.inputs,
    outputs: options.outputs,
  };
  return Directive(metadata)(class MockDirectiveClass {
  });
}

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
      PrintSidebarComponent,
      MockDirective({ 
        selector: '[skinColorPicker]', 
        inputs: []  // <--- empty, unless the directive has inputs
      })
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Component is Directive without template, we could directly use [MockComponent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-mock-component). I guess the 'MockDirective' is also inspired by it.

Way of using MockComponent to mock directive is as follows:

```
MockComponent({
  selector: '[skinColorPicker]',
  inputs: ['skinColorPicker']
}),
```